# Test Method to cover SendEmail method with arguments

Tags: unit-test, send-email

I am a beginner to SFDC and stuck in between to write a test method to cover the `SendEmailNotify()` in one of my class.

**Class**

```
private void sendEmailNotify(String[] FailedRecords, String strErrRoutine, String strErrType, String strErrText){
        Map<string,list<string>> mapToCCEmailAddresses = new Map<string,list<string>>();
        mapToCCEmailAddresses  = ZEBUtility.getOutboundEmailAddresses();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.setToAddresses(mapToCCEmailAddresses.get('TO'));
        mail.setCcAddresses(mapToCCEmailAddresses.get('CC'));
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test Display');
        mail.setSubject('Custom Revenue Forecast - Error of Type : ' + strErrType + ' in Routine : ' + strErrRoutine);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('ERROR : ' + strErrText + FailedRecords); 
        mail.setHtmlBody('ERROR : <b> ' + strErrText +' </b>' + ' <p> <b> ' + FailedRecords + '</b>');

        // Sending error notification email.
        try{
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        } catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Error sending email notification ' + e);
        }
```

**Test**

```
@IsTest private class testClass { 
    private void testMethod testSend(){ 
        MainClass controller = new MainClass(); // where Mainclass is the name of class in which my SendEmailNotify() method is defined.
        test.startTest(); 
        PageReference page = controller.SendEmailNotify();
        System.assert(page == null); 
        test.stopTest(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which errors do you face when you try to write your test?

Comment: If your have written a test already post it and we can help. Otherwise write it and post it and we can help

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line in test class

```
PageReference page = controller.SendEmailNotify();
```

and try this.

```
PageReference page = controller.SendEmailNotify(new List<String>{'Test1', 'Test2'}, 
                                                'Test',
                                                'Test',
                                                'Test');
```

`SendEmailNotify` method expects 4 parameter like list of string and string variables.

Comment: Thanks Reshma for replying on this. When I try to implement with your suggestion then I got the error like 'Method is not visible.[MainClass].sendEmailNotify(List, String,String,String)'. Please suggest on this.

Comment: @NoviceSfdc Make sure to add `@Testvisble` before your `sendEmailNotify` method in controller class